# deleting entries in History tab of Task Schedule for specific task?

Tags: windows-10, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler

I have Task History enabled in the Task Scheduler and am wondering if there's a way to delete entries in the Task History tab for a specific task.

Case in point: I'm trying to diagnose an issue and only want to see the newest entries. I don't care about all that historical data.

Comment: I think the only way would be to reduce the size of the event log for Task Scheduler.   Look at the last post in https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e5bca729-52e7-4fcb-ba12-3225c564674c/scheduled-tasks-history-retention-settings?forum=winserver8gen

Comment: @DrinkMorePimpJuiceIT - sorry for not responding sooner! Sometimes the more involved answers require more time and effort to verify and what not lol. It's ironic - it's those answers that are most deserving of rep points but it's also those answers that take the most time to verify and all that jazz lol

Comment: @neubert I appreciate that very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As inspired by the PowerShell logic used in the [Get-scheduled task to see history for more than last run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58012201/get-scheduled-task-to-see-history-for-more-than-last-run/58012445#58012445) post, using [get-winevent](https://ss64.com/ps/get-winevent.html) and the `-FilterXml` parameter along with the task's full path and task name, you can get the data from the task history of a specific task since the last x seconds, minutes, hours, days, etc.

You can use [where-object](https://ss64.com/ps/where-object.html) along with the `TimeCreated` properties of the event data to only get data from a specific date or time frame.

Use [get-date](https://ss64.com/ps/get-date.html) and wrap a parenthesis around it, and then pick the one of the "`.add`" `hours()`, `minutes()`, `days()` and so on methods with a `-1` in it for minus 1 from the current date e.g. `.AddHours(-1)` where 1 could be any number to subtract from the current date.

[image]

---

Use the [Get-ScheduledTasks](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/get-scheduledtask?view=win10-ps) to get the full path and task name of the specific task to put into the portion of the `-FilterXml` to specify the task name.

### PowerShell Part 1

```
$TaskName = "MyCool Task Named Cool";
Get-ScheduledTask | % { Process { If ( $_.TaskName -eq $TaskName ) { "$($_.TaskPath)$($_.TaskName)" } } };
```

**Output**

```
\Taskpath\MyCool Task Named Cool
```

**Note:** *This above value will be copied into the below PowerShell.*

### PowerShell Part 2

Plug the output of the above command into the value between the single quotes in the `*[EventData/Data[@Name='TaskName']='output goes here']` line below.

```
$events = @(
     Get-WinEvent  -FilterXml @'
     <QueryList>
      <Query Id="0" Path="Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler/Operational">
       <Select Path="Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler/Operational">
        *[EventData/Data[@Name='TaskName']='\Taskpath\MyCool Task Named Cool']
       </Select>
      </Query>
     </QueryList>
'@ -ErrorAction Stop 
)
$events | ? {$_.TimeCreated -ge (Get-Date).AddHours(-1)} | FL
```

**Output**

```
TimeCreated  : 2/24/2021 10:04:54 PM
ProviderName : Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler
Id           : 110
Message      : Task Scheduler launched "{e372dfef-0c52-4358-bb0a-efb60d3f178b}"  instance of task "\Taskpath\MyCool Task Named Cool"  for user 
               "Cool" .

TimeCreated  : 2/24/2021 10:04:54 PM
ProviderName : Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler
Id           : 200
Message      : Task Scheduler launched action "F:\Picking\Nose4\AwesomeSause.exe" in instance "{e372dfef-0c52-4358-bb0a-efb60d3f178b}" of task 
               "\Taskpath\MyCool Task Named Cool".

TimeCreated  : 2/24/2021 10:04:54 PM
ProviderName : Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler
Id           : 100
Message      : Task Scheduler started "{e372dfef-0c52-4358-bb0a-efb60d3f178b}" instance of the "\Taskpath\MyCool Task Named Cool" task for user 
               "DrPC123\Nurse".

TimeCreated  : 2/24/2021 10:04:54 PM
ProviderName : Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler
Id           : 129
Message      : Task Scheduler launch task "\Taskpath\MyCool Task Named Cool" , instance "F:\Picking\Nose4\AwesomeSause.exe"  with 
               process ID 15956.
```

### Supporting Resources

- [Get-WinEvent](https://ss64.com/ps/get-winevent.html)

  > ```
  >    -FilterXml XmlDocument
  >        Use a structured XML query to select events from one or more event logs.
  >
  >        To generate a valid XML query, use the Create Custom View and
  >        Filter Current Log features in Event Viewer.
  >        Use the items in the dialog box to create a query, and click the XML tab to view the XML query. 
  >
  >        Typically, you use an XML query to create a complex query that contains several XPath statements. 
  >        The XML format also allows you to use a "Suppress" XML element that excludes events from the query.
  >
  >    -FilterXPath string
  >        Use an XPath query to select events from one or more logs.
  > ```
- [Get-ScheduledTasks](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/get-scheduledtask?view=win10-ps)
- [Where-Object](https://ss64.com/ps/where-object.html)

  > The '`?`' symbol and Where are both aliases for Where-Object. If you
  > explicitly want to run the Where-Object command, run Where-object or
  > '`?`'